# Python generator function with predicate

Tags: python, iterator, generator

```
def group_func(iterable,p):

    for i in iterable:
         yield [i]
         if p(i):
             yield i
```

I'm working on group_func

However, the group_func I defined above could not do this...obviously. Any help?

Comment: Your `hide` function can be replaced by the builtin `iter`, I think. I'm assuming its purpose is to make you deal with iterators, rather than other kinds of iterables (like sequences) directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to split words like this?

```
def hide(iterable):
    for v in iterable:
        yield v

def group_func(iterable,p):
    result = []
    for i in iterable:
         result.append(i)
         if p(i):
             yield result
             result = []
    yield result


print([v for v in group_func('combustibles', lambda x : x in 'aeiou')])
print([v for v in group_func(hide('combustibles'), lambda x : x in 'aeiou')])
```

Comment: You might want `if result: yield result` at the end, so you don't yield an empty list.